# how convert string to object in javaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

i have used Object.parses() but getting error

```
var obj = '
   "users": [
 { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"},
 { "name":"Mike", "age":25, "city":"new jersey"},   
]'
```

Comment: What is the  error that you are getting? and what is Object.parses()?

Comment: Did you mean `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: I'd suggest that you use `JSON.parse()` except that the string you've posted isn't valid JSON

Comment: Yes JSON.parse is right if you want to parse a object

Comment: var obj = `{
   "users": '[
 { "name":"John", "age":'30', "city":"New York"},
 { "name":"Mike", "age":'25', "city":"new jersey"}
]'}`

i have used JSON.parese(obj); then getting following error;


SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON

Comment: @Owaisp that still isn't valid JSON. and it isn't valid JavaScript either. You need to pay closer attention to what you're typing. Using an IDE which can highlight syntax errors, and also a JSON checker like https://jsonlint.com/ would probably help you sort your code out before you run it. See my answer below for a summary anyway.

Comment: the JSON.parse() method doesn't output very helpful error messages. But there are plenty of open-sourced JSON validators with more helpful error messages out there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you haven't mentioned JSON explicitly, this data looks like JSON. You can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to turn JSON strings into JavaScript variables

However, the string you've posted isn't actually valid JSON because of a couple of syntax errors. You can fix those to get (what I assume is) the intended object structure:

1) remove the extra double-quote before `new jersey`

2) add curly braces at either end to make it into a valid object.

3) remove extra comma after the last array entry (although a lot of parsers will tolerate this in fact)

So you end up with

```
{ 
  "users": [
    { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"},
    { "name":"Mike", "age":25, "city":"new jersey"}
  ]
}
```

And this can be parsed easily:

```js
var obj = '{ "users": [{    "name": "John",    "age": 30,    "city": "New York"  },  {    "name": "Mike",    "age": 25,    "city": "new jersey"  }]}';

var data = JSON.parse(obj);

console.log(data);
console.log("----------");

//example of gettng a specific property, now it's a JS variable
console.log(data.users[0].name);
```

Comment: I have used the same but when i assigning the following string object
var string = `{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "Andrew",
      "pets": [
        { "name": "Layla", age: 12 },
        { "name": "Poopers", age: 2 },
        { "name": "Noelle", age: 1 },
        { "name": "Huckleberry", age: 1 }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Sergio",
      "pets": [
        { "name": 'Athena', age: 4 },
        { "name": 'Anubis', age: 8 },
        { "name": 'Fluffy', age: 1 }
      ]
    },
  ]
}`


JSON.parse() is not working for this

Comment: That's because it isn't JSON, it's already an object, you don't need to parse it into a new object. JSON.parse() expects to be given a string value, not an object. Remember: JSON is a way of writing objects within a string (so you can send it in a HTTP request, for example). If you're just declaring a variable then that's nothing to do with JSON, and you don't need JSON for that. To make that data be JSON within a JavaScript context you would have to enclose it in quote marks so that JavaScript sees it as a string. And then you could parse that, just like the example in my answer.

Comment: ...But it's usually only useful to parse JSON if the data has come from another source rather than being hand-written into the code. My answer is just a theoretical example (based on what you were trying to do in your original code in the question).

Comment: this data i m getting as string its not a object.

Comment: The way you've written it in your comment, i.e. `var string = { "users": [....` show that it's not a string - you've started with a `{`. That makes it an object literal. If you were creating a string it would start with `var string = '{ "users": [...` i.e. adding a `'` quote mark at the start. But also that would give you other problems - you've got single quotes within the data instead of doubles (e.g. `"name": 'Athena'`). If it _was_ a string, that would make the JSON invalid. JSON (unlike JavaScript) requires all property names and all string values to be always double-quoted.

Comment: You can use a tool like https://jsonlint.com/ to quickly check whether your data would be considered as valid JSON or not.

Comment: This demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q93uLb6r/2/ quickly shows you the difference. The first variable `obj` is your object as shown in your comment above. Notice how when I log it to the console, it already shows up as an object. The second variable `string` is your same data, but modified to be valid JSON (all properties double-quoted, all string values double-quoted, extra commas removed). Then from the two log commands you can see the difference before parsing and after parsing. I hope that helps you to clarify in your mind the difference between JSON and an object literal in JavaScript.

Comment: P.S. If my answer and comments have helped you, please remember to mark the answer as "accepted" (by clicking the tick mark next to the question so it turns green) and/or give an upvote - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, correct your string. It should look like  on inserted snippet.
Second, use JSON.parse()

```js
var t = '{"users": [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"},{ "name":"Mike", "age":25, "city":"new jersey"}]}'; 
    
     
     var obj = JSON.parse(t);
     console.log(obj["users"][0].name);
     console.log(obj["users"][0].age);
     console.log(obj["users"][0].city);
```